# Infinite Loop when trying to print all the ASCII values

Tags: loops, ascii, infinite

I seem to be getting an infinite loop when I try to print all 128 ASCII values and I don't understand why. The question asks me to write a program that uses a loop to display the characters for the ASCII codes 0 through 127 and to display 16 characters on each line. I tried using a for loop and told the program to stop looping if my char variable goes past 127 but for some reason I end up getting an infinite loop. I even wrote an if-statement telling the loop to break if the char variable goes beyond 127 but that doesn't seem to work either. Here is my code, any feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a;

    for (char a = 0; a <= 127; a++)
    {
        cout << a << " ";
        if (a % 16 == 0)
            cout << endl;
        if (a > 127)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not that it matters, but you actually have *two* `a` variables there, the one in the `for` statement shadows the other. You probably also don't want to actually *print* the values `0..31` or `127`, they're non-printables in ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `char` type is almost certainly a signed one (C/C++ allow `char` to be signed or unsigned <sup>(a)</sup>) so, when you add one to `127`, it's wrapping around to `-128` (not actually *mandated* by the standard, but common behaviour).

Hence it's *always* less than or equal to `127`.

You can test that with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char x = 127;
    x++;
    cout << (int)x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If that is the case, just use `unsigned char` rather than `char`.

---

Here's some code that does the job, while also only printing out the characters specifically marked as printable:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned char a = 0;
    while (a < 128) {
        if (isprint(a)) {
            cout << a << " ";
        } else {
            cout << ". ";
        }
        if (++a % 16 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ?
@ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _
` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o
p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ .
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> From `C++ 17, basic.fundamental`:

> a plain `char` object can take on either the same values as a `signed char` or an `unsigned char`; which one is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `char` datatype has a range from -128 to 127. This also means that when you get to `a = 127` and then `a++`, it loops back to `a = -128` and then continues. Therefore when you look at the condition of `a <= 127` it will always be true. One option might be making an unsigned type

Answer (score -1):

char is ansigned symbol, 
so a + 128 = a

which means that when a == 127, a++ gives you 128 -> a = 0 so the condition is still true

you can fix it with =
if (a >= 127) break;

or use do {} while (a != 127)